# How to ask for a newer software version?

Tags: updates

I would like to know what's the recommended procedure to submit a request for a newer software version?

An example: I really like gThumb a lot, but the current version in Ubuntu 13.04 & 13.10 is 3.0.2. The last gThumb is 3.2.3 and was released this last august.  So, how to submit the request about refreshing a software like gThumb?

Thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write to [Technical Board](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TechnicalBoard) to add the software to [MicroReleaseExceptions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates/MicroReleaseExceptions)

Comment: Thanks a lot Webby. The Micro Release Exceptions procedure is pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Generally It's rare for software to be updated between major releases except where it fixes a security problem or significant bug.  But if enough people want it or the changes are significant enough it may be possible.

The correct procedure is to report a bug against the package on Launchpad.

For gthumb the link would be [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gthumb)

Include as much detail as you can.

However if you look [here](https://code.launchpad.net/gthumb) you will see that 3.2.10.11 has been uploaded so it may appear in the next version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks Warren for the general procedure. But for the gThumb specific case, you're wrong. After some discussions on the mailing list, it seems that there is no people who took care of the gThumb evolution in Ubuntu. Nothing more. This should be fixed in a near future.